# Determining Bayesian Classifier

Tags: probability, machine-learning, bayesian

Consider a 2-class Pattern Recognition problem with feature vectors in $R^2$. The class conditional density for class-I is uniform over $[1, 3]×[1, 3]$ and that for
class-II is uniform over $[2, 4] × [2, 4]$.

Now I have two questions.

1. Suppose the prior probabilities are equal. In such a case, the Bayes classifier is given by $x + y = 5$.
2. If the prior probabilities are changed to $p1 = 0.4$
   and $p2 = 0.6$, what is the Bayes classifier now?

I solved the first part kinda "graphically" and intuitively, but I don't know how to solve the second one. Any help, hint or a solution, will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Analytically" you can proceed using Bayes theorem .

Using graphical intuition , note that the non-uniform priors "favor" a class over the other , so the points at the intersection have now a higher probability to belong to the second class .

Comment: Can you please provide some steps for obtaining the result analytically?

Comment: Express the conditional probability using Bayes theorem as $p(y=1|x) \sim p(x|y=1)p(y=1) $ and  $p(y=2|x) \sim p(x|y=2)p(y=2) $ . To find the Bays classifier , think about the points that separates the region in the plane where the first quantity is greater the the second one .

Comment: I don't understand how I'm supposed to "think about the points that separates the region in the plane...". Like even if I am somehow able to do it in this one, what if my input space is how high dimension, say 10?

Comment: Well , usually finding Bays classifier it not feasible . In this toy example it's easy because all your points are located in one of the two rectangles and computing the class probability for each one is easy .

Comment: I understood how we can proceed in this question at least. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome !